# How to stop drop-down submit form appending url?

Tags: html, forms

I have constructed a drop-down menu that once an item from the list is selected and the submit button clicked, it will send the end user to an external url. However, the form is appending the url which causes issues with a particular external website from recognising the url and returns an error (this is something the website has suggested would happen to stop tracking appending).

**Example:** 
Normal url - https://google.com - is changed to - https://www.google.com/?=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com&gws_rd=ssl

Furthermore, it depends which browser you use. Safari, Fierfox and Chrome are fine. However, IE or Edge cause the error on the website.

Is there anything I can change in the code below to prevent the url from being appended????

```
<form method="get" action="http://example.com/">
<select name="" onchange= "this.form.action=this.value">
 <option value="0">Please Select</option>
 <option value="http://google.com">Google</option>
 <option value="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
 </select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the GET method

```
<form method="get" action="http://example.com/">
```

It append value at the end of your URL to send them to your form handler

If you don't want those value to be seen you should use POST method

```
<form method="post" action="http://example.com/">
```

Have a look over there https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp and there https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

Comment: Thank you. This has prevented the url from being appended. However, the website on IE continues to disallow the url even though it isn't appended in the browser. Works on chrome, safari and firefox. What does the post actually do to the url?

Comment: `POST` and `GET` are different method to send you form, basically with `GET` your trying to get some informations and with `POST` you are trying to send some informations (I add another link on my answer)

Comment: What do you mean by disallow ?